# How to get out the date validation to another separate function

Tags: javascript, html, function

I want to take out the date validation(a validation to my code to validate year between 1930 and the current year and if it's not correct it should print an error) to another separate new function, Instead of the Addmovie function.

i want to make another new function called datevalidation and I want to add date validation, which is currently in the addmovie function.

HTML Code

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
         
         <title>Week 07 Pass Submission</title>
        <script src="./w7p.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
        <header>
        <h1>Week 07 Pass Submission</h1>
        </header>
        <article>
        <form>
        <label for="movie">Movie title</label>
        <input type="text" id="movie" /><br /><br />
        <span id="yearValidation" style="color: red"></span>
         <br />
        <label for="year">Release year</label>
        <input type="text" id="year" /><br /><br />
        <input type="button" id="add" value="Add">
        <input type="button" id="show" value="List All">
        </form><br />
        <div style="padding-left: 20px;" id="list"></div>
        
        </article>
         
        </body>
        </html>
```

JavaScript Code

```
var movieTitle = [];
var movieReleaseYear = [];
function init() {
  var add = document.getElementById('add');
  add.onclick = () => addMovie(2022);
  var show = document.getElementById('show');
  show.onclick = () => displayData();
}

function addMovie(currentYear) {
  var name = document.getElementById('movie');
  var year = document.getElementById('year');
  var year = document.getElementById('year').value;
  if (year <= 1930 || year >= currentYear) {
    document.getElementById('yearValidation').innerHTML = 'Error';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('yearValidation').innerHTML = '';
  }
  movieTitle.push(name.value);
  movieReleaseYear.push(year.value);
}

function displayData() {
  if (movieTitle.length == 0) {
    document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = 'there is no data';
  } else {
    var output = '';
    movieTitle.forEach(
      (element, index) =>
        (output +=
          ' ' +
          (index + 1) +
          '. ' +
          element +
          '\t\t' +
          movieReleaseYear[index] +
          '<br />')
    );
    document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = output;
  }
}
window.onload = init;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a separate function `dateValidation()` and call it inside `addMovie()`

```
var movieTitle = [];
    var movieReleaseYear = [];
    function init() {
      var add = document.getElementById('add');
      add.onclick = () => addMovie(2022);
      var show = document.getElementById('show');
      show.onclick = () => displayData();
    }
    
    function dateValidation(year,currentYear){
      if (year <= 1930 || year >= currentYear) {
        document.getElementById('yearValidation').innerHTML = 'Error';
      } 
      movieTitle.push(name.value);
      movieReleaseYear.push(year.value);
    }
    
    function addMovie(currentYear) {
      var name = document.getElementById('movie');
      var year = document.getElementById('year').value;
      dateValidation(year,currentYear);
    }
    
    function displayData() {
      if (movieTitle.length == 0) {
        document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = 'there is no data';
      } else {
        var output = '';
        movieTitle.forEach(
          (element, index) =>
            (output +=
              ' ' +
              (index + 1) +
              '. ' +
              element +
              '\t\t' +
              movieReleaseYear[index] +
              '<br />')
        );
        document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = output;
      }
    }
    window.onload = init;
```

Comment: @jtk Please tick if you got the answer.